# No matching function for call?

Tags: c++, templates, function

Can't figure out why im getting this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘write_vector(int&)’
```

```
    template <typename T>
    void write_vector(const vector<T>& V)
    {
       cout << "The numbers in the vector are: " << endl;
      for(int i=0; i < V.size(); i++)
        cout << V[i] << " ";
    }

    int main()
    {
      int input;
      vector<int> V;
      cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
      cin >> input;
      V.push_back(input);
      write_vector(input);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: eheheheheheh...you're passing integer but it's expecting vector.

Comment: Please spend 1 minute re-reading your code and thinking about the type you're passing in to `write_vector`.

Comment: try placing the template in a header file.

Comment: @johnathon: that's not the problem here.

Comment: @Mat Thanks! I've overlooked it.

Comment: yea, he's passing the wrong thing into his function

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
write_vector(V); //V is std::vector<int>
```

instead of

```
write_vector(input); //input is int
```

Please try to understand the error message. It gives much of the hint as to what went wrong in your code.

Also, it seems you've written `using namespace std` somewhere in your code. Dont do that. Erase that line. And then use `std::vector` where you use `vector`. That is better coding-style which can avoid many problems caused by `using namespace std`, especially in a big projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing your input variable into the function , and your template function expects a vector. Try passing in V insted

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to write_vector function using the wrong parameters. On the code you just posted, you are calling to the procedure using 'input' as a parameter, but 'input' is 'int' type not 'vector'.